# retrieve email using c#?

Tags: c#, pop3

I want to retrieve emails from my Go Daddy account using C#. I tested [OpenPop.NET](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/) to do that like so:

```
    OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client PopClient = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
    PopClient.Connect("pop.secureserver.net", 995, true);
    PopClient.Authenticate("username", "pass");
```

My problem is that the server does not accept the user credentials. I'm sure the credentials are OK.

I have tried the same code with my Gmail account and every thing goes OK. Is something missing that Go Daddy wants me to set?

Is there another a .NET tool like [OpenPop.NET](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/) that I can use to retrieve emails using the POP3 protocol?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found out that `OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword` is the missing part. I have modified the code to be following and it works.

```
OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client PopClient = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
PopClient.Connect("pop.secureserver.net", 995, true);
PopClient.Authenticate("username", "pass", OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
```

Comment: I used this plugin to read emails, it worked well but it doesn't reads the body of the mail. It happened with you or not?

Answer (score 1):

Port 995 is Secure POP3 which doesn't have to be supported by your mail provider.

Use 110 for regular POP3.

Comment: i also tested like that  PopClient.Connect("pop.secureserver.net", 110, false); the same error

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because your email account is not configured for Pop by default.
Go to settings in your email account and enable pop.